# What is !! mean in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, syntax, resttemplate

- I'm maintaining a microservice system was written in Kotlin and Spring-boot and at some code, I found !! syntax which i don't know what it meaning:

```
fun getListOrderStatus(orderStatusAgentRequestDto: OrderStatusAgentRequestDto): ResponseEntity<List<OrderStatusAgentResponseDto>>? {
        val accessTokenAgent = agentAuthService.getAccessTokenAgent()
        val requestUri = UrlBuilder(mposApiEnpoint.orderStatusListRead)
                .addParam(HttpUtils.PARAM_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessTokenAgent!!.accessToken)
                .addParam("page_size", "${orderStatusAgentRequestDto.pageSize}")
                .addParam("order_codes", if (orderStatusAgentRequestDto.orderCodes != null) orderStatusAgentRequestDto.orderCodes.joinToString(separator = ",") else "")
                .addParam("modified_time", "${orderStatusAgentRequestDto.modifiedTime}")
                .addParam("service_id", "${orderStatusAgentRequestDto.serviceId}")
                .toString()
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()

        return restTemplate.exchange(requestUri, HttpMethod.GET, null, object : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<OrderStatusAgentResponseDto>>() {})
    }

....
....
val status = orderMappingApi.getListOrderStatus(agentRequestDto)
val orderStatus = status.body!![0]
```

- The status was the response of a above function. Can somebody please explain to me what !! mean and what its use in this case? Thank in advance!!!

Comment: I think this is typo it should be || for "OR".

Comment: Very similar but i think @ShivamSharma got the right answer

Comment: it's better to add a null checking before we set it as a non-null type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!! in Kotlin is the not-null assertion operator. it converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if the value is null.

```
val len = query!!.length
```

if query is not null it will return its length but if query is null we'll get NPE.

Comment: It seem like the IDE automatic recommend add it. Can i replace it with ?. syntax?

Comment: Yes you can replace it with ?. for null safety. In your case orderStatus  will be set to status.body[0] if status is not null otherwise it will be set to null but if you use status.body!![0] it will throw NPE if status is null otherwise it will also return status.body[0]